# View/Download .pdf of storage firebase from web

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a .pdf document in my firebase storage. I want to see or dowonload the .pdf document. I want to call this function from .html

Any template?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

All files stored in Firebase have a unique URL to them. Just create a function that downloads the file via the URL.

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow anyone to download *any* file from Cloud Storage (including PDF), you'll have to generate either a [download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) (from a mobile client using the [Cloud Storage for Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/)), or generate a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) using a Cloud SDK.  This is a just a regular URL that any browser can download.